# How to get async data that is required on next page before moving on to next page C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin, architecture

I have two pages. The first page is a menu and the second page is the data. I choose an option in the menu and that triggers an async method that downloads the data from the database which is then displayed on page 2.

In my mind I have to options on how to implement this and I can't figure out which one is better.

Option 1 - something like this:

```
public void NavigateToPageTwo()
{
      var myData = Task.Run(async () => { return await GetData(); }).Result;
      Navigate(myData);
}

public async Task<MyData> GetData()
{
     return await some method...
}
```

Run GetData synchoniously blocking the thread while the user stares at a spinning wheel and then when the data has arrived move onto the next page and pass the data as a parameter or set it as a static field somewhere doesn't matter just do nothing untill the data has arrived.

Option 2

```
 public async void NavigateToPageTwo()
 {
      subscribe to an event here that will trigger when data arrives
      await GetData();

 }

  public async Task GetData()
  {
     await some method...
     fire an event after data has arrived
  }

  void OnEvent()
  {
       navigate to page two after the event has fired
  }
```

Whatis the most appropriate approach out of these two or maybe some other way is better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Wait() option in Task

```
public void NavigateToPageTwo()
{
      var task = GetData();
      task.Wait(); //Wait till finish the task
      var myData = task.Result;
      Navigate(myData);
}

public async Task<MyData> GetData()
{
     return await some method...
}
```

Comment: Sure, You can use .Result too, what I am saying is that is it better to do it this way or implement an event driven asynchronous pattern https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/implementing-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern